# Type Hinting List of Strings

Tags: python, function, var, python-typing

In python, if I am writing a function, is this the best way to type hint a list of strings:

`def sample_def(var:list[str]):`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use the `typing` module

```py
from typing import List

def foo(bar: List[str]):
    pass
```

The reason is `typing` contains so many type hints and the ability to create your own, specify callables, etc. Definitely check it out.

Edit:
I guess as of Python 3.9 `typing` is deprecated (RIP). Instead it looks like you can use `collections.abc.*`. So you can do this if you're on Python 3.9+:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def foo(bar: Iterable[str]):
    pass
```

You can take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html for a list of ABCs that might fit your need. For instance, it might make more sense to specify `Sequence[str]` depending on your needs of that function.

Comment: In my opinion, if you recommend something despite it being deprecated, you should more clearly say why.

Comment: Hmm, what do you have against the way they show in the question?

Comment: @KellyBundy it doesn't have any backwards compatibility with things like Python 3.7 so it seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: That might be an argument against it, yes, though not in the 3.9+ part of your answer. Also, 3.9 is 500 days old, so probably many people are using it (or 3.10) by now :-). And you can already use in 3.7, with `from __future__ import annotations`.